# Huge difference in iperf output of two arch

Tags: linux, networking

I see huge difference in results of iperf for aarch64 and riscv64. what could be the reason? can someone please help? I Have checked and compared below parameters,

```
1.nic statistics
2.kernel tuning parameters.
3.netstat output
4.ethtool -s eth0 output
```

Do i need to check any hardware setting for it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more details on your comparison , are you sure, you have exactly the same network hardware on both ? or not the same distrib on both etc...

Answer (score 0):

> Distribution details: RISCV (Yocto build distro)[image] : Linux 5.10.41 #1 SMP Mon Jan 17 12:01:30
> UTC 2022 riscv64 riscv64 riscv64 GNU/Linux  RPI(Gentoo): Linux pi64
> 5.4.45-v8-3b41649ff96d-p4-bis+ #2 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 16 14:11:43 GMT 2020 aarch64 GNU/Linux

PFA for network hardware difference.

Thanks